# React JS import css file had expression no-unused-expressions

Tags: reactjs

In my React JS app add import a CSS file in component 
`import("./assets/Base.scss");` 
When run  `npm start` show this error in command prompt

`Line 17:1:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions`

Line 17:1 is `import("./assets/Base.scss");`

I don't want to import css file like below
`import './assets/Base.scss';` 
I want to import with parenthesis .

I had some rules for`.eslintrc.js` :

```
"use strict";

const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

const restrictedPaths = [
  { name: "react-bootstrap" },
  { name: "@material-ui/core" }
].map(pkg =>
  fs
    .readdirSync(path.dirname(require.resolve(`${pkg.name}/package.json`)))
    .map(component => ({
      name: `${pkg.name}/${component}`,
      message: `This loads CommonJS version of the package. To fix replace with: import { ${component} } from "${pkg.name}";`
    }))
);

module.exports = {
  extends: "eslint-config-react-app",
  rules: {
    // "no-script-url": "warn",
    "jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid": "warn",
    "no-restricted-imports": ["error", { paths: [].concat(...restrictedPaths) }]
  }
};
```

How can I solve this problem? 
Is the error displayed for rules in`.eslintrc.js`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write it like this:

```
import "./assets/Base.scss";
```

Without the parenthesis

Comment: I know it. But I want to use import with parenthesis

Comment: @Mohammad Daliri Why?

Comment: I already saw a project use this way.
I want to know how to use this method in my project. I think to change the rules of `.eslintrc.js` but I don't know how